# Store accented word into Sqlite - iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, non-ascii-characters

I coulnd not find a solution.
I store data into a local SQLITE DB. Everything works except for accented words.
As in the figure.

[image]

However, if I try to store accented word by using SqliteManager (Firefox plugin) everything works. In conclusion: when I store accented word by using my app, strange chars appear.
I use the following code to write data (same for read). Basically, all strings are UTF8 encoded.

```
-(NSInteger)writeData:(NSDictionary* )data table:(NSString* )table
{
    sqlite3_stmt    *sqlStatement;
    NSMutableArray  *columns   = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray  *values    = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:data];
    @try {
        assert([data count] != 0);
        if ([[data allKeys] count] == 0) return 1;


        [temp removeObjectForKey:@"id"];
        [columns addObjectsFromArray:[temp allKeys]];
        NSString        *cols      = [columns componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        NSMutableString *colNames  = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:
                                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %s (",[table UTF8String]]];

        [colNames appendString:cols];
        [colNames appendString:@")"];

        // VALUES FOR  INSERT
        [values addObjectsFromArray:[temp allValues] ];
        NSMutableString *s = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        for(int i = 0; i < [values count]; i++)
        {
            [s setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[values objectAtIndex:i]]];
            const char* currentValue = [s UTF8String];
            [values setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%s\"",currentValue] atIndexedSubscript:i];
        }
        NSString        *vals       = [values componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        NSMutableString *valNames   = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@" VALUES ("];
        [valNames appendString:vals];
        [valNames appendString:@")"];

        [colNames appendString:valNames];
        const char *sql = [colNames UTF8String];
#ifdef DEBUG
         NSLog(@"avvDB writeDATA insert string %@",colNames);
#endif

        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement write %s",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            return 0;

        }
        if (sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
           // NSLog(@"Last id %llu %s",sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db),sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }

    }// end try
    @catch(NSException* e)
    {
        NSLog(@"Eccezione in write %@",[e reason]);
    }
    @finally {
        sqlite3_reset(sqlStatement);
        sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
        sqlStatement = nil;
        return sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db);
    }


}
```

Comment: By the way, when you call `sqlite3_prepare` (and you probably should use `sqlite3_prepare_v2`), you then call `sqlite3_step` to execute it (which returns `SQLITE_DONE` upon successful update), not `sqlite3_exec`. And if you `sqlite3_bind_xxx`, you definitely want to step through prepared statement, not `sqlite3_exec`. Also, you don't have to call `sqlite3_reset` unless you're resetting your prepared statement to bind new values, which you are not doing here. `sqlite3_finalize` is sufficient here.

Comment: Re `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, the [docs say](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html), "The `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` and ... interfaces are recommended for all new programs. The two older interfaces [namely `sqlite3_prepare()`] are retained for backwards compatibility, but their use is discouraged."

Comment: This does not matter with the problem of accents..

Comment: Which is why they're comments, not part of the answer. And, in fact, the failure to call `sqlite3_step` is peripherally related because it will render the `sqlite3_bind_text`, as described in my answer, ineffective. And the failure to call `sqlite3_prepare_v2` will result in cryptic error messages if you actually have any problems. Regardless, my apologies for the unsolicited advice regarding these other mistakes. No offense was intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%s` operator does not support unicode characters. As the [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) of the *String Programming Guide* says, it is "Null-terminated array of 8-bit unsigned characters."

Frankly, for other reasons, you shouldn't be using `stringWithFormat` anyway (what if one of the strings had a quotation mark in it ... your SQL statement would fail; you're even exposed to SQL injection attacks). You should be using a `?` placeholder instead (with no quotation marks), and then call [`sqlite3_bind_text`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) for each of the parameters you want to bind to the respective question mark (note, `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions use a 1-based index, unlike `sqlite3_column_xxx` which use a 0-based index).

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot the basics!